# second datepicker closes instantly

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I use the following code to in my web site to use jquery datepicker.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({  
            inline: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            beforeShow: function(elem){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var buttonPane = $(elem).datepicker("widget").find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" ); 
                    var btn = $('<a class="ui-datepicker-clear ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all">Clear Dates</a>');
                    btn.unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
                        $.datepicker._clearDate(elem);  
                    });  
                    buttonPane.empty();
                    btn.appendTo(buttonPane); 
                },1);
            },
            onChangeMonthYear:function(elem){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var buttonPane = $(elem).datepicker("widget").find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" ); 
                    var btn = $('<a class="ui-datepicker-clear ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all">Clear Dates</a>');
                    btn.unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
                        $.datepicker._clearDate(elem);  
                    });  
                    buttonPane.empty();
                    btn.appendTo(buttonPane); 
                },1);
            },
            onClose:function(){
                $('#to').datepicker('show');
            },
            onSelect:function(date,inst){
                $('#to').datepicker('show');
            }
        });
```

But when I select a date, the second datepicker opens and closes instantly as it open. Is there any thing wrong that I'm doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's related to a timig issue, try to use a settimeout and inside the function open the second datepicker.

I added a check to avoid the `to` element to open itself when closed.

Code:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    beforeShow: function (elem) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var buttonPane = $(elem).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
            var btn = $('<a class="ui-datepicker-clear ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all">Clear Dates</a>');
            btn.unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
                $.datepicker._clearDate(elem);
            });
            buttonPane.empty();
            btn.appendTo(buttonPane);
        }, 1);
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (elem) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var buttonPane = $(elem).datepicker("widget").find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
            var btn = $('<a class="ui-datepicker-clear ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all">Clear Dates</a>');
            btn.unbind("click").bind("click", function () {
                $.datepicker._clearDate(elem);
            });
            buttonPane.empty();
            btn.appendTo(buttonPane);
        }, 1);
    },
    onClose: function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') === 'to') return true
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(this)
            $("#to").datepicker('show');
        }, 10);
    },
    onSelect: function (date, inst) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') === 'to') return true
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#to").datepicker('show');
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8M5dD/